# Переместить запись из кастомного типа поста в др. рубрику при наступлении условия (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть кастомный тип постов "Мероприятия". В нем две рубрики: ближайшие и архивные. Понятно, что при создании все события попадают в ближайшие. А как сделать так, чтобы после прошествия дня события, оно автоматически меняло рубрику, а не админ вручную переставлял привязку. С помощью acf7 создано кастомное поле даты. И есть следующий код:

```
function update_event_taxonomy() {
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'event_date',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '<',
            'type' => 'DATE',
        ),
    ),
);
$event_posts = get_posts($args);

foreach ($event_posts as $event_post) {
    $event_date = get_field('event_date', $event_post->ID);
    $event_tax = ($event_date < $today) ? 'archive' : 'upcoming';
    wp_set_post_terms($event_post->ID, $event_tax, 'events_category', false);
}
```

}

```
function schedule_event_taxonomy_update() {
if (!wp_next_scheduled('update_event_taxonomy')) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'update_event_taxonomy');
}
```

}

```
add_action('wp', 'schedule_event_taxonomy_update');
```

Однако при его выполнении, с тех событий, которые подпадают под условие чекбоксы с "ближайшие мероприятия" снимаются и к архивным они не привязываются, чекбокс не проставляется.

Где ошибка или как это правильно/лучше сделать?

Comment: Правильно - менять статус, а не рубрики. Рубрики не для этого нужно использовать.

Comment: @SeVlad А подробнее, если можно? Как мне статус "опубликовано, черновик, на утверждении" должен помочь? Спасибо!

Comment: Добавляешь статус "архив"... https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_post_status